# Can we create a readonly file from SSRS subscription report

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

I have a SSRS Subscription report 2012, it store the file at a shared library location is it feasible with SSRS to create a readonly file when it render the RDL.

Comment: What about using Active Directory instead?

Comment: If you are worried some one will alter a excel file, how about saving as a pdf?

Comment: We are working with financial data so we cannot move with pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can execute the dos command `attrib +r report.xls` after the subscription runs

behind the scenes, subscriptions are sql agent jobs. so you just have to find the right sql agent job and add another step into it.